# Android activity life cycle - restarting (destroying) app does not remove reference to (custom) listener?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, lifecycle, renderer

I have an application using a GlSurfaceView and renderer. I have it set so that when the user exits the application via the back button I call myActivity.finish();

This is fine and I can see the activity getting calls to onStop() and onDestroy();

The app works fine the first time run however when I subsequently run I have had a problem with my motionEvents.

I handle motion events by queuing them into a pool and having the renderer access the pool at the right time like so:

```
try
    {
        //Get the history first
        int hist = event.getHistorySize();
        if (hist > 0)
        {
            //Oldest is first in the list. (I think).
            for (int i=0;i <hist; i++)
            {
                InputObject input = inputObjectPool.take();
                input.useEventHistory(event, i);
                defRenderer.feedInput(input);
            }
        }

        //The current one still needs to be added
        InputObject input = inputObjectPool.take();
        input.useMotionEvent(event);
        defRenderer.feedInput(input);
    }
```

And in the renderer:

```
            synchronized (inputQueueMutex) 
    {
        ArrayBlockingQueue<InputObject> inputQueue = this.inputQueue;
        while (!inputQueue.isEmpty()){try
            {
                InputObject input = inputQueue.take();

                if (input.eventType == InputObject.EVENT_TYPE_TOUCH)
                {
                    screenManager.processMotionEvent(input); 
                }
                else if (input.eventType == InputObject.EVENT_TYPE_KEY)
                {
                    screenManager.processKeyPress(input);
                }

                input.returnToPool();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                DLog.defError("Interrupted blocking on input queue.", ie);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the above code I hand these motion events to the ScreenManager which basically is my way of having several "scenes" which I render out. This works fine the first time I run the application and the screen interprets my motion touches into movement of a simple square at the moment.

However the second time I run the application the square is drawn to the screen fine however the motion events do nothing.

I have followed the motion events and although they are given to the "new" renderer it seems to be giving the motion events to an old screen. Or rather to an old object on the screen. This is confusing as in my code in the onCreate() method I do this:

```
//Set up the renderer and give it to the SurfaceView
    defRenderer = new DefRenderer();
    defView = new DefView(this);
    defView.setRenderer(defRenderer);

    //Set out content to the surface view.
    setContentView(defView);

    //Set up the input queue
    createInputObjectPool();
```

OnCreate is called both the first time and the second time my app is run (and the app was destroyed!) the screens are made new in defRenderer and are given to a new defView.

I am very confused how data could remain in the defRenderer to receive the motionEvents as the app is completely remade.

Is there something obvious going on that I am missing here? I would have thought that when onDestroy is called the app would be completely dereferenced and so no trace of it would remain. Is this not true? Does somehow when I call new Renderer(); is it referencing an old one?

I am at a loss as to what is going on really. Especially as this app is a basic copy of another I have written which works completely fine!

EDIT:

After a small amount of experimentation I have discovered that the motion events are actually going to an old ScrollPanel (an object I made..) which is registered as a listener (and by listener I mean my own implementation ..) for MotionEvents. I have made my own event system for these like so:

```
public interface TouchSource 
public static final int TYPE_TOUCHDOWN = 0;
public static final int TYPE_TOUCHDRAG = 1;
public static final int TYPE_TOUCHCLICK = 2;

public Vector<TouchListener> listeners = new Vector<TouchListener>();

public void addTouchListener(TouchListener listener);
public void removeTouchListener(TouchListener listener);

public void touchOccured(int type, int xPos, int yPos);
```

}

And the listener interface:

```
public interface TouchListener 
public boolean touchDownOccured(int xPos, int yPos);
public boolean touchDragOccured(int xPos, int yPos);
public boolean touchClickOccured(int xPos, int yPos);
```

So the Screen implements touchSource and so has a list of the listeners. Now despite being REMADE by Screen currentScreen = new Screen(); called in the OnCreate(); of the manager this list of listeners is still populated with the old ScrollPanel?

How is this? I'm clearly missing something obvious. Like somehow the list of listeners is static for some reason and not getting dereferenced despite the app being completely remade?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you're facing might have something to do with the fact that the original motionevents are recycled (returned to their pool) by the framework after the `onMotionEvent()` returns.

From the way you're using your InputObjects, I think you might be keeping a reference to the original motionevents in there, and not copying the event data.

Quickly try using `MotionEvent.obtain(event)` whereever you use `event` now (this makes a copy) and see if this makes the weird behaviour go away. Naturally, if this works you will eventually have to recycle() those copies after you're done with them. Do not call `recycle()` on the original motionevents though.

Cheers, Aert.

Comment: Having discovered that the app is actually storing an old reference to a motionListener I made I do not think it is to do with the Events themselves. However I am very confused as to how an app that has been destroyed could still retain references to a static. Edit: However I will try!

Comment: Hm, having looked at my code (I'll be honest, I'm a little drunk now) I do not seem to actually store the events themselves "input" objects are my own and I copy across fields such as the type of action and the position of the event. In my input pool I simply have 10 of these and allocate / return as needed. I guess my question with this is, when an app is destroyed are all references removed? So when I start an app again is it a fully blank sheet? At the moment I seem to have a static list of objects in an interface that remains. I think a static list in an interface is probably a bad thing.

Comment: Yeah every field in an interface is implicitly public final static. I think you answered your own question: an interface shouldn't keep any state and implementation, but you are using the list in such a fashion which causes problems... Still puzzling why the state is not reset when the app is restarted. This would indicate the interface is not unloaded when the app is closed.